# How can you find a list of devices attached to an android device?

Tags: android, raspberry-pi

I recently got the [Pine64](https://www.pine64.com/product) development board and got Android on it. I want to use the available USB ports (for a gps receiver) but I do not know if android detects them. I was wondering if there's a way to find any available usb ports or devices connected to them.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can think about 3 possible ways:

1. If you just want to debug the connection, there are some quick tools on Google Play, such as [this App](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.reboucas.utils.usb).
2. If you have root privilege, consider build a statically linked `usbutils` so you have `lsusb` on Android. It seems that a few people have tried this, you can google "usbutils android".
3. Recent Android version provides [API for enumerating USB devices](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html). It is not too hard to write a small App to do so. On github there are a bunch of such codes, e.g. [this](https://github.com/illarionov/ExternalGPS/blob/master/ExternalGPS/src/main/java/ru0xdc/externalgps/usb/UsbUtils.java).